# is one local scope property array for temporary results better than many global variables?

Tags: javascript

If you search for script solutions online the provided examples often declare all variables as global with `var a = 'something'; var b = 123;` before the function is staring an algorithm on those variables. Then within the functions sometimes more global variables are declared to hold in between results up to the point the function returns the output of whatever the algorithm is doing.

I wonder now if declaring one single variable once inside the function within an object as an array to hold all in-between results as properties is or isn't more efficient?

For example is example1 or example2 causing more memory usage when the loop would be 100.000 times?

A global function using global variables in a loop

```
var a = 10, b = 2.33, s = 'example1'

function do1000Times(a,b,s) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
     var half = a/2;
     var multi = half*b;
     result += s+' half of A multiplied by B = '+multi+"\n";
     a = half;
  } // end of loop
  console.log(result);
  return result;
} // end of function

do1000Times(a,b,s) // execute the function
```

vs an object with just local parameters doing the same loop

```
const run1000Times = {
    temp : [],
    result : '',
    run : function(val1,val2,str) {
        this.result = '';
        for (this.temp.i = 0; this.temp.i < 1000; this.temp.i++) {
         this.temp.half = val1/2;
         this.temp.multi = this.temp.half*val2;
         this.result += str+' half of A multiplied by B = '+this.temp.multi+"\n";
         val1 = this.temp.half;
        } // end of loop
    console.log(this.result);
    return this.result;         
    } // end of run
} // end of object

run1000Times.run(10, 2.33, 'example2') // execute run inside object
```

A less readable syntax but maybe faster/more efficient because of the absolute array references?

```
const loopXTimes = {
    temp : [],
    run : function(val1,val2,str,loop) {
     this.temp[3] = ''; // [3] holds result
      for (this.temp[0] = 0; this.temp[0] < loop; this.temp[0]++) {
        // temp[0] holds iteration count
         this.temp[1] = val1/2; // [1] holds result a;
         this.temp[2] = this.temp[1]*val2; // [2] holds result b;
         this.temp[3] += str+' half of A multiplied by B = '+this.temp[2]+"\n";
         val1 = this.temp[1];
        } // end of loop
  console.log(this.temp[3]);
  return this.temp[3];      
  } // end of run
} // end of object

loopXTimes.run(10, 2.33, 'example3', 1000);
```

Comment: Typed Array is fastest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray

Comment: usually or let's say in most cases faster is also more memory efficient, or not?

Comment: In general you focus on either time or space effectivenes. It is hard to get both. Interestingly optimization need more code to get it faster.

Comment: I think you get a good question if you ask something like: Is there a time difference in call to a deep structure with objects in object or to flatten the structure to more global variables. Maybe it is another question?

Comment: Do I correctly understand form your comment about using a Typed Array, that example3 with `temp : []` at the first line inside an object whereafter only 4 temporary variables will be needed should be slower than having `temp : new Int8Array(4)` at the first line?

Comment: or no, an Int8Array cannot hold a string or float, so it should be Float32Array(3) plus an extra result property for the string, right?

Comment: Oh no - forget about typed Arrays! It is only for very advanced problem solving to parse the bytes from binary files.

Comment: `return this.result` as a value and `return this.temp[3]` is equally fast, but with `return this.temp` you can return three values with one copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples have no differences at all with respect to scope. Both use only local variables. The parameters are also local.

If one function use global variables and the other function use local variables there is no difference in memory usage.

To use constants in comparision `< 1000` or variables `< loop` with loop set to 1000 makes no difference. Javascript internally optimize to whicheffer is the most effective.

To use the newer keywords `const` or `let` over `var` makes coding more specific and safe. It gets not faster or lessen not memory consumtion. The scope is closer with `let`, but it doesn't make any difference compared to a binding as far as in another object. A binding is just a binding to a variable or a constant - same speed and a memory location of same size (32 bits).

Essentially every variable have exactly the same memory usage of 32 bits. It is how Javascript is implemented to work best in general. Use (time consuming) bit operations to store 32 booleans in a variable if you must, but otherwise just let the few booleans in a program have it's use of 32 bits each. It is the size of a memory location that fit the hardware best. To store more in memory locations you also can look into [typed arrays](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/).

In a loop it is no difference to have the bindings into variables in a lot of different objects or to flatten it to have the variables directly in a loop. It is one step bindings in both cases. Javascript optimize by make local declarations to global if nessecary. It also optimize deep dot-referencing to one step bindings.

Sometimes it may be better to reference directly into objects instead of making a a lot of copies by assigning variables. *Each copy (instance) requires both space and time*. For example passing an object instead of its values is better. Javascript has pass by value meaning object reference is only one value to pass.

The most of time there is no use of try micro-optimize the code because the internal compiler optimization takes care of it.

**Now to answer your question**: *is one local scope property array for temporary results better than many global variables*?

Global variables stored in the window object is generally not a good practice. If the window object has to be looped (that I doubt the internal JS do) it takes more time. But the dot-operation (with `.key`) is still same speed independent of size or where in memory it is. Also indexing (with `['key']`) is the same - actually `obj['key']` equals `obj.key`. **Everything in Javascript is Object**, even arrays!

If you mean global variables in a function compared to store it in an array *it has no time or space differences at all* when talk about retrieving value from variable compared to indexing or referencing - it is the same. The compiler see those just as bindings to values in memory.

Compared array of size 1000 to have same data in 1000 variables in code has still no memory gains after compilation and optimization. Compiler store variables in a memory chunk (that may be seen as an array).

Comment: Ah ok I will test it at jsperf.com to compare examples. But just now read your answer saying it's no difference. Also added example3, but then guess thats also no big difference either. Anyone maybe knows of a way to test memory usage rather than operations per second?

Comment: Essentially every variable have exactly the same memory usage of 32 bits. It is how Javascript is implemented to work best in general. May sound strange that a boolean false/true need 32 bits. Then you need to know bit operations to store 32 booleans in a variable.